# ILayer to IFeatureLayer casting problem in VBA

Tags: arcobjects

I am facing problem with `ILayer` to `IFeaturelayer` casting in ArcObjects(VBA) after casting debugging time it is showing error message. Run-time error(Type Mismatch). error getting at ****

```vb
 For i = 0 To pMap.LayerCount - 1                        
     Set pLayer = pMap.Layer(i)
     MsgBox (pLayer.name)                        
     Dim pFlayer As IFeatureLayer
     **** Set pFlayer = pLayer ****
     If (Not pLayer.name = "ParcelNumbers") Then                            
         Set OtherFClass = pFlayer.FeatureClass
         InterCount = OtherFClass.FeatureCount(pslt)                            
         If (Not InterCount = 0) Then
             objTextStream.WriteLine pFeature.Class.AliasName & "," & pFeature.oid & "," & "Fuse Overlapping with other feature."                                
         End If
     End If
 Next i
```

Comment: First test if pLayer.Valid then test if typeof pLayer is IFeatureLayer https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/typeof-operator before casting to pFlayer. Your layer could be a raster layer or group layer etc.. and not implementing IFeatureLayer so can't be cast to one.

Comment: Thank you so much Michael. Actually my layer in Parcel Fabric that way it is getting error.

Comment: I would recomment using `pMap.Layers(uidForIGeoFeatureLayers, True)` to prevent such errors, see: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IMap_Layers.htm

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @MichaelStimson:

> First test if pLayer.Valid then test if typeof pLayer is IFeatureLayer
>   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/typeof-operator
>   before casting to pFlayer. Your layer could be a raster layer or group
>   layer etc.. and not implementing IFeatureLayer so can't be cast to
>   one.

and if you get an error in your Parcel Fabric, then as commented by @Berend:

> I would recommend using `pMap.Layers(uidForIGeoFeatureLayers, True)`
>   to prevent such errors, see:
>   https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IMap_Layers.htm